# Exchange rate for last a few hours

Tags: python, exchange-server, rate, forex

Greeting...
I need to read historical data for exchange rate for last a few hours (2 or 3) in python. I got one that read data for days
Is this method is a practical. or I need to use API ?

```py
import  duka.app.app as import_ticks_method
from duka.core.utils import  TimeFrame
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from1 = datetime.date(2020,1,1)
to1 = datetime.date(2020,1,3)
Assets=['EURUSD']
import_ticks_method(Assets,from1,to1,1,TimeFrame.TICK,'',True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could make your question a little bit more clear (I'm a bit confused with how your code relates to the question) it would probably help you get a better answer.

In any case, if you can easily get all of the data you need conveniently on disk (ie: export it all to `data.txt`) then there's no need for API. This is the simpler solution.

However, if you want to check new data every 2-3 from some external resource (`www.get_data.com`) then you'll need to use an API; probably you'll want to take a look at the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library, which makes getting data from some api on the web quite easy.

Comment: I need python code that can bring last exchange rate 2-3 hours in minutes or seconds from forex

Comment: Then you'll want to use the API. It looks like they have a website that offers that service [see here](https://fixer.io/)